# Sharepoint 2016 eval in Azure - public access

Tags: azure, public-website, 2016

I need to make Sharepoint accessible publicly for this evaluation. I've seemed to get it where I can access the site with a specific url (something like .cloudapp.net//

this url prompts for a user and I am able to get logged in. But after that, if I click on anything it seems to break. I get a 401 unauthorized after that. I am unsure if my site collection/web app is setup incorrectly.